# Query and signal in the same trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I try to create a log system with a trigger in MySql (5.7.21), on a constraint test:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `before_insert_grp` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `grp`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF 
     NEW.grp_n_entree > 50
THEN        
   INSERT INTO logs (logs_d_date, logs_v_message)  
      VALUES (NOW(), 'Entrées supérieures à 50'); 

    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
   SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Entrées supérieures à 50';
END IF;
END;
```

It runs the signal but not the insert query into the logs table. I've added SIGNAL command because the query in the trigger does not work : no insert into the logs table but insert done into the grp table.

Any idea? Thanks.

PS : I run this in PhpMyAdmin (last version).

Comment: Any chance that the table logs is InnoDB and grp in MyISAM?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure table `logs` is created using MyISAM storage engine.

If the table uses InnoDB storage engine, the INSERT performed by the trigger will be rolled back when the error (SQLSTATE > '02') is thrown. (That is, the INSERT in the trigger not executed as an autonomous transaction, it terminates just like the calling statement terminates when the exception is thrown.)